# Form input with graphic background

Tags: html, css, svg

I would like to give users the opportunity to input some text in a few colored shapes. Is it a good strategy to design the shapes in (for instance) illustrator, export as svg and put the input tags (or textarea's) in the svg file?

Other ways of doing this?

[image]

Comment: Please read [ask] and [mcve]

Comment: This can easily be done via css

Comment: Viewing your example images; the best way to do this is with pure CSS. It is easy, smart and universal.

Answer (score 2):

This is a simple example of doing what you're looking for with CSS - a starting point for you to work from.

(The CSS can be simplified down but I kept it deliberately  verbose so you can see what's going on and where)

```css
.text {
  display:block;
  width: 60vw;
  margin: 1rem 20vw;
}
.textleft {
  display: inline-block;
  width:49%;
  margin: 1rem 0;
  padding:0 9% 0 5%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.textright {
  width:49%;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 1rem 0;
  padding:0 5% 0 9%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.txtarea {
  width:100%;
  color: #000;
  height: 7rem;
  font-size:1rem;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  padding:1rem;
  border: none;
  border-radius:2rem;
  resize: none;
  overflow:hidden;
}

#red {
  background-color: #c00;
  color: #eee;
}
#green {
  background-color: #0c0;
}
#blue {
  background-color: #33f;
  color: #ccc;

}
#yellow {
  background-color: #ff0;
}
```

```html
<div class='text'><textarea id='red' class='txtarea' name='myinfo_top'>Some Words - Click on me to type into this text box!</textarea></div>

<div class='textleft'><textarea id='green' class='txtarea' name='myinfo_left'>Some Left Words</textarea></div>

<div class='textright'><textarea id='blue' class='txtarea' name='myinfo_right'>Some Right Words</textarea></div>

<div class='text'><textarea id='yellow' class='txtarea' name='myinfo_bottoms'>Some more Words</textarea></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Create div tag that will contain elements of height and width, if you want rounded corners you might use `border-radius` in CSS.

```
div{
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

Then you can add whatever text you would like. Its the best option, adding image in the background, it takes a lot more processing time than pure CSS.